# How to reverse the digits of a given number and then find the sum of that number in C++ from an user input?

Tags: c++

I've been working on this problem for an hour now and can't seem to find a solution. The question is to reverse a given number from an user input first, and then with that given number(not the reversed one) find the sum of its digits.

Using these two functions: a) int reverseNumber(int n); b) int S_of_Number(int n).

Here is the code that I've done so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int reverseNumber(int n){
int reversedN = 0, rem;
cout << "Give a number: ";
cin >> n;

while(n!=0){
rem = n%10;
reversedN = reversedN * 10 + rem;
n = n/10;
}
cout << "Reversed number is: " << reversedN << endl;
}; 

int S_of_Digits(int n) {
int rem, S=0;
while(n>0){
    rem=n%10;
    S=S+rem;
    n=n/10;
}cout << "The sum of digits is:  " << S;
}

int main(){
int n;
reverseNumber(n);
S_of_Digits(n);
}
```

Comment: Surely the digit sum is the same for both the forward and reverse numbers.

Comment: Ok but how can I connect them to find the sum? Cuz thats the problem up till now

Comment: My ***guess*** is that you should read the value in the `main` function, then pass them to the functions. And the functions should probably *return* some result, which you then print in the `main` function. Hard to tell exactly what's wanted from your assignment since you don't tell us. Please **[edit]** your question to include a full and complete copy-paste (as text) of the assignment.

Comment: The two functions are declared to *return* `int`, but they do not return anything.  Instead, they write representations of their results to `cout`.  The computations themselves look correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that solved it!

Comment: Also, the number should probably be read outside of `reverseNumber()` and passed to that function as its argument.

Comment: Handy trick: If the input is being taken as formatted text, a number encoded as characters, you can read it into a `string` and then operate on the `string` where the digits are already nicely separated for you. At that point `std::reverse becomes an easy option as do reverse iterators.

Comment: Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 0):

> Using these two functions: a) int reverseNumber(int n); b) int S_of_Number(int n).

Those function signatures seem to indicate that each function should receive the number to operate on as its argument, and return the result as its return value.  However, each function writes its result to `cout` instead of returning anything.

Moreover, the main function passes the value of an uninitialized variable to each function.  This is irrelevant for your implementation of `reverseNumber()` because it ignores its argument and instead reads a number from `cin`, but

1. Ignoring its argument is presumably incorrect, and
2. The number it reads is local to that function -- `main()`'s like-named variable is distinct and unaffected.

You should instead prompt for and read the input in `main()`, call the functions, then print the output in main.  Overall, then, something like this:

```
// ... function implementations ...

int main(void) {
    // ...
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int reversed = reverseNumber(n);
    int digit_sum = S_of_Digits(reversed);
    cout << "Reversed number is: " << reversed << endl;
    cout << "The sum of digits is:  " << digit_sum;
}
```